# Using pure function (For Each) to change array, failing Jest

Tags: javascript, foreach, jestjs, pure-function

I am trying to use a pure function that is using For Each, the function will change input array to return 'x'. Can someone help me explain why I am getting this error?

Functions:

```
let functions = {
    helper: (x) => {
        return x;
    },

    changeArray: (x) => {
        let arr1 = [x];
        arr1.forEach(functions.helper);
        return arr1[0];
    }
};
```

Test file:

```
test('For Each', () => {
    expect(syntax.changeArray(['hey', 'hi']).toBe(['x','x']));
})
```

Result/Error:

```
    TypeError: _syntax.default.changeArray is not a function

      73 | 
      74 | test('For Each', () => {
    > 75 |     expect(syntax.changeArray(['hey', 'hi']).toBe(['x','x']));
         |                   ^
      76 | })
```

CHANGES:

```
const syntax{    
    helper: (x) => x,

    changeArray: (arr) => {
        return arr.map(syntax.helper);
    }
}
```

TEST FILE:

```
    test('For Each', () => {
       expect(syntax.changeArray(['hey', 'hi'])).toBe(['x','x']);
    })
```

RESULT:

```
    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    - Expected
    + Received

      Array [
    -   "x",
    -   "x",
    +   "hey",
    +   "hi",
      ]
```

Comment: I just edited, but realized I can't tell if the "helper" and "changeArray" functions are defined inside of an object named "functions" or "syntax". It looks like you reference it by both those names.

Comment: Can you include your code where you define `syntax`?

Comment: Your `helper` function still has an Error. It is currently returning `x`, a variable. It needs to return `'x'`, a string

Comment: Your `changeArray` function still has an Error. It's missing a `return` statement, and will always return `undefined` instead of the mapped `Array` - or you can just copy-paste the exact function I've already written for you

Comment: That's because you didn't properly copy my code. Your `changeArray` function is erroneously always returning `undefined`

Comment: There is a big difference between `arr => arr.map(fn)`, and `arr => { arr.map(fn); }`

Comment: Is there a way I can keep it in the curly brackets since I am calling changeArray function in the test file so I can return the correct values? I have edited the updates.

Comment: If for some reason you need those curly brackets, you can use `arr => { return arr.map(fn); }` (this is 100% equivalent to `arr => arr.map(fn)`)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with this

Main one is, what is `syntax.changeArray` ? Your function is in `functions.changeArray`.

When you run a function through `Array.forEach`, the `forEach` function literally doesn't do anything with the returned value. I think what you want is `Array.map`

Also, your helper function returns `x`, not `'x'` -- it will return whatever its given, so if you DID pass that helper function to `array.map`, it would just return the same unchanged value you send it.

This bit of code might hopefully give you an idea of what you should be doing.

```js
function runMap(arr) {
  return arr.map(val => 'x');
}

var testArray = [1,2,3];
console.log(runMap(testArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are we seeing references to both `functions` and `syntax`, which seem identical? Let's stick to one, and delete the other. I'll use `syntax` here.

Here's a definition of `syntax` that should fix your problems:

```
let syntax = {

  // This change to the "helper" function solves problem #1;
  // simply return the string 'x' regardless of the parameter
  helper: x => 'x',

  // This "changeArray" function return a new `Array` where
  // every item has been mapped using `syntax.helper` (which
  // will map every Array item to the string 'x'):
  changeArray: arr => arr.map(syntax.helper)

};
```

Fix the logic error in your test suite. Change:

```
expect(syntax.changeArray(['hey', 'hi']).toBe(['x','x']))
```

To:

```
expect(syntax.changeArray(['hey', 'hi'])).toBe(['x','x']);
```

Comment: I see! Thanks, I've tried to adjust the code now but I am receiving Cannot read property 'toBe' of undefined error in test.


    helper: (x) => x,

    changeArray: (arr) => {
        arr.map(syntax.helper);
    }